# Finding the distance from the flat surface to the point of tangency between two circles with having radii $2$ and $10$ respectively

Tags: geometry, circles

I have had trouble with this problem lately.

Question:

> Assume there are two circle with radii $2$ and $10$. The both circle are tangent to each other and are on a flat surface. Find the distance from the flat surface to the point of tangency between the circles.

[image]

Please consider the large radius and small radius with the mentioned information. Thanks,
NJC

Comment: What do you mean by 'Find the distance from the flat surface to the point of tangency between the circles'?

Comment: I would suggest you draw the situation, and draw it well! Then start drawing auxiliary lines, triangles that show up ...

Answer (score 1):

**An alternative method:** Let the flat surface be the $x$ axis and $(2,2)$ be the center of the small circunference. In order for the two circumferences to be tangent to each other, the big circumference has to have its center at $(2+\sqrt{80},10).$ As the point of tangency is on the line that connects the centers of the two circunferences, it needs to be a convex combination of them. In particular, as it is at a distance of $2$ from $(2,2)$ and a distance of $10$ from $(2+\sqrt{80},10)$ it should be

$$ \frac{10}{12}(2,2)+\frac{2}{12}(2+\sqrt{80},10)=(2+\frac{\sqrt{80}}{6},\frac{10}{3}),$$

so the distance to the $x$ axis is $\frac{10}{3}.$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $A$ be the radius of the small circle and $C$ be the radius of large circle. Connecting those necessary point, we get $AC = 12$, $GC = 8$ and $AB = PI = 2$. We need to find out the $|HI|$.

$\triangle ACG \sim \triangle AHP$ and so

$\frac{HP}{AH} = \frac{GC}{AC}$ $\implies HP = \frac{8×2}{12} \implies HP = \frac{4}{3}$

Hence, distance from the flat surface to the tangent point ,$HI = (HP+PI) = (\frac{4}{3}+2) = \frac{10}{3} \approx 3.33$

Comment: Minor issue: $AC=12$, so, in fact, $HP=\frac{4}{3}$ and $HI=\frac{10}{3}.$

Comment: @Patricio You are right. I corrected my mistake. Thank you for showing that.